# Blog post preview shows <font if cuts off the rest after it

Tags: php

```
    if (strlen($body) > 2000)
                    {
                        $body = substr($body, 0, 2000);
                        $body .= '...<a href="/blogpost/' . $id . '/' . urlencode($title) .'">Read More</a>

';
                }
```

So say i have `<font size="5">` when it cuts it off, its like "`And he was like<font...Read More`". It shows the word `<font` on the screen for the end user to read, because it didn't get a chance to close because it was truncated. Is there a fix or work around for this? Its kinda annoying to be like this.

Comment: stop using a decade old html and learn css

Comment: It would do the same thing right? <div id=" that can be cut off also... I was using font as an example.

Comment: yup, i just hate <font>, would striping tags first work, or break it? otherwise its rather hard but theres probably some regex.

Comment: I don't really want to strip tags 100%. just remove the word <font or whatever if its not closed.

Comment: on the manual page for substr() there are a few user notes on how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When truncating HTML for abbreviated views, I recommend throwing a `strip_tags` first, generally you don't really need formatting/links on abbreviated content, imo.

```
$plainBody=strip_tags($body);
$abrvBody=strlen($plainBody)>2000?susbtr($plainBody,0,2000):$plainBody;
```

If you must keep your formatting/links, you can always clean up the chopped text with `preg_replace`

```
$cleanAbrvBody=preg_replace('/<[^>]+$/','',susbtr($body,0,2000));
```

Though you may end up with un-closed tags.

Answer (score 0):

Use :

```
strip_tags()
```

...It will help.